# how to load Laravel 6 model classes without namespace

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I am new to Laravel and I was working on Laravel 4. I am trying to migrate to Laravel 6 on docker and I have the basic setup and Laravel project is up.

I created a table and a respective Eloquent Model in the models folder. I am able to read the data in a controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use mysql_xdevapi\Exception;
use  App\Models\Card;

class welcomeController {
    public function show() {
        try {
            $cards = Card::all();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            die("Could not connect - " . $e );
        }

        print_r($cards); exit;
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Card extends Model
{

}
```

In the older version of Laravel project, the 'Card::all()' was working without using USE command to import it.

I know namespaces are important, but wondering how it worked and how I can make replicate the same.

Comment: "*In the older version of Laravel project, the 'Card::all()' was working without using USE command*" - I'm on an older version of Laravel, and I can confirm this is **not** the case. If you don't import a class, it'll default to the namespace of the current class, in this case `App\Http\Controllers`, and you don't have a class `App\Http\Controllers\Card`. Although, Laravel 4 is a very old version... Maybe it was like that, but regardless. You need to import them correctly in current versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why you want to discard using namespaces, If you want to NOT use `namespaces` for your models, edit your `composer.json` like below

```html
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories",
        "models"
    ]
},
```

Make a directory in your root directory and add a new file i.e 'models/Card.php'.

below should be the content of your `Card.php`

```html
<?php 

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Card extends Model {

    //database table here
    protected $table = "cards";

    //Fillables
    protected $fillable = [];
    
}
```

And in your controller `WelcomeController`

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use mysql_xdevapi\Exception;

class welcomeController {
    public function show() {
        try {
            $cards = \Card::all();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            die("Could not connect - " . $e );
        }

        print_r($cards); exit;
    }
}
```

Do not forget the forward slash in your card model i.e '\Card::all()'

Make sure to move your `models` folder outside the `app` directory, Kindly note this is not `php` best practice

Comment: I had the models inside the app directory and had added "app/models" in the autoload, but did not work. I will try this. Thanks

Comment: It did not work. i am getting undefined index: model error. Could "  'models' => App\User::class " in the auth.php under providers be causing an issue?

Comment: You need to `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Try when the model folder is in app i.e "app/models" also

Comment: I have tried all of the above. But unable to get it work. Anything else I might have missed. Thanks!

Comment: Also fix this `class welcomeController` capitalize your class name `class WelcomeController`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204451/discussion-between-bodi87-and-kikuyu1).

Comment: I have edited my answer, now it should work. I have tried and it works fine, probably what you missed is the forward slash \Card::all()